# Файловый вывод в определенное место

Tags: c++

у меня есть файл `qwer.h`. В нём написано `hello, misha`. Я хочу добавить слово `dear` после `hello`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
        std::ofstream ff1{"qwer.h", std::ios::ate};

        ff1.seekp(5, std::ios::beg);

        ff1 << "dear" << std::endl;;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

В итоге, в файле `qwer.h` я получаю следующее: `^@^@^@^@^@dear`. Я пробовал поменять `std::ofstream ff1{"qwer.h", std::ios::ate};` на `std::ofstream ff1{"qwer.h", std::ios::ate | std::ios::app};`, но тогда слова просто добавляются в конец файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот здесь можно почитать про флаги открытия потока:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode

Если кратко описать суть, то `std::ios::app` вам никак не поможет, т.к. при установленном этом флаге перед каждой операцией записи курсор будет установлен в конец потока, независимо от того куда вы перемещали его раньше. `std::ios::ate` также устанавливает курсор в конец потока при его открытии, но не перемещает его туда при записи. Так как вы открыли поток только с эти флагом, то программе ничего не известно о том, какие данные уже есть в этом потоке, поэтому, после `ff1.seekp(5, std::ios::beg);` он переставляет курсор на пять символов от начала и после выполнения строки `ff1 << "dear" << std::endl;` Заполняет первые 5 символов нулями и перезаписывает остальное.

Для того, чтобы вставить текст в нужное место, вам нужно добавить флаг `std::ios::in`, т.е. должно получится так: `std::ofstream ff1{ "qwer.h",  std::ios::in | std::ios::ate };`.Это позволит программе получить уже имеющиеся данные в потоке. Хотя, по большому счету, `std::ios::ate` вам даже не нужен, т.к. вы считаете от начала, а не от текущей позиции. В итоге открыть поток можно так: `std::ofstream ff1{ "qwer.h",  std::ios::in | std::ios::out };`. Флаг `std::ios::out` разрешает запись в поток. Однако это все равно не даст вам желаемого результата, т.к. у вас сохранятся первые пять символов потока, далее **заменятся** 4 символа на dear и выведется остаток потока. Т.е. вы получите что-то наподобие: `Hellodearha`. Для того чтобы именно вставить новые символы  с сохранением остальных, правильнее всего будет использовать временный поток, в котором вы сформируете полностью все что вам нужно, а потом скопируете в целевой.

P.S. надеюсь понятно объяснил :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо